# ¿Se puede agregar una validación para evitar comentarios que empiecen con +/-?

Tags: característica-nueva

Este es un ejemplo claro de la pregunta del título (fuera del contenido de la pregunta y del comentario en sí mismo):

[+1 Por incluir la atribución al artículo original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146/por-qu%C3%A9-se-procesa-m%C3%A1s-r%C3%A1pido-un-array-ordenado-que-uno-desordenado/147#comment146_146)

La funcionalidad sería similar a la del sitio en inglés:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es probable implementar esta funcionalidad también en este sitio bajo la misma causa: *No comentes en tus votos. Por favor escribe comentarios constructivos y detallados que se enfocan en el contenido de la publicación*?

Comment: ¿Estas a favor o encontra de empezar los comentarios con +/-? ¿Por qué?

Comment: @Rubén estoy a favor de que el sitio en español tenga por lo menos las mismas funcionalidades que el sitio en inglés hasta que fue lanzado el beta privado. La funcionalidad que menciono ya existe desde hace un tiempo en el sitio en inglés, y mi duda es por qué no está implementado en el sitio en español, que lo considero más un bug.

Comment: No sé si será un bug o no. No creo que lo sea porque he visto que en otros sitios de SE si se permite el uso de -1 al inicio de un comentario y por ello pienso que se trata de una configuración especial, seguramente solicitada por la comunidad de SO.

Comment: @Rubén en todo caso pediría que se implemente también acá utilizando el mismo motivo: *No comentes en tus votos. Por favor escribe comentarios constructivos y detallados que se enfocan en el contenido de la publicación.*

Comment: Considera actualizar tu pregunta. Por cierto, el [artículo de ayuda correspondiente](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) está pendiente de ser traducido, lo cual podría estar relacionado con que esté pendiente de implementarse.

Comment: @Rubén la pregunta ya está actualizada, incluyendo los tags :)

Comment: jeje, fuiste más rápido de lo que tardó en refrescarse la pestaña :)

Comment: @Rubén si entiendo cómo funcionan las cosas, soy usuario veterano de stackoverflow. Por eso saltó mi duda primero como bug (similar al clásico usuario quejón) pero ya está escrito con más paciencia y de manera de solicitud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No recordaba haber leído esa parte de la documentación

En todo caso estoy de acuerdo en que se debe implementar acá también.

Por cierto ya eliminé mi comentario al cual hace referencia la pregunta